# Slow performances with mx:Datagrid

Tags: performance, apache-flex, datagrid

I have one `mx:datagrid` with nearly 100 rows and 10 columns. I want to have effects on cells when data change (green or red fade with duration 2s).

I receive data from `xmlSocket` and actualisations may occured frequently. 2-3 Cells in average are actualised per second.

Performances are catastrophic...it's impossible to see any fade on cell.

I tested to debug my item renderer which produces the effect and realized that it was called on any modification in the `dataprovider`. So if there is data modification on row number 10, all the item renderer in any row are called...is this the right behaviour ?

I expected that only the item renderer which displays new data would be called not alla others.

Comment: Don't remember how rendering works in the old datagrid, but if you can you should definitely switch to the Spark DataGrid.

Comment: I use mx:Datagrid because drag/drop solution is not implemented in Spark DataGrid (I think).

Comment: Seems like the feature's been added somewhere in the last Apache Flex versions (see http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/DataGrid.html#dragEnabled), though the version number in the docs says 5.0 (which doesn't exist yet). I checked the code and it has been implemented, so I suppose the version number just means to convey that this is an experimental feature.

Comment: I've just checked on simple example s:DataGrid and when we add or modify data, all item renderers are called so it's the same bahaviour as mx:DataGrid. Tomorrow I will test with the new Appache Flex version as suggested, thanks

Comment: Ok I've just tested with Apache SDK and I think it's a little bit faster. I have open another topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730148/flex-sdatagrid-all-itemrenderer-are-fired to explain better my problem. Thanks for helping me